# How to move or transform mask except layer which we will add a mask to?

Tags: gimp

I added mask to the layer:

[image]

Then I want move or scale\transform it:

[image]

But any attempt leads to the fact that the mask is transformed simultaneously with the layer:

[image]

But I need:

[image]

**I redraw mask** to to fit the result with scale, move and flip.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the layer and its mask are always linked.

You can copy the mask to a layer to edit it:

- While editing the mask: Edit>Copy
- Edit>Paste as>New layer

And when done editing that layer, copy the layer back to the mask:

- Edit>Copy
- Click on the mask in the Layers list to make it the target
- Edit>Paste
- Layer>Anchor (which will actually merge the floating selection in the mask)